# Json from two list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have two list.
first list has got 8. And I wanna use them as key. 
For second list I have over 500 row. If we imagine as a csv first list header second list values.Each row will be value of first row's key. But I have no idea how can I convert it as json? Json library hasnt got like csv ; DictWriter. So what is the step?
I will share example codes for my example thanks a lot.

```
header = [
        "Company",
        "MRP",
        "Product",
        "Selling_price", #first list
    ]
mainrow = [[
        "TEST1",
        "MRP",
        "Carrot",
        "5", #second list first row
    ],
           [
        "TEST2",
        "MRP",
        "Cheese",
        "10", #second list second row
    ],
     ... #second list n row
```

Comment: When looking at a CSV, when looking at a file, it is a comma delimited list, where each line is the next row.  So if you create a file called:  test.csv, and then write out the header as `",".join(header) + "\n"` then you can write out the array as well in a similar fashion.

Comment: I forgot to take my laptop that is why I cant share with you source code. Found it;
{"Kanal": "2000'ler", "Frekans": "11012", "Polarizasyon": "V - Dikey", "Kapsama": "Batı", "SR": "30000", "FEC": "5/6", "V-PID": "120", "A-PID": "220", "Uydu": "T3A"}
{"Kanal": "24 HD", "Frekans": "12310", "Polarizasyon": "V - Dikey", "Kapsama": "Batı", "SR": "15000", "FEC": "3/4", "V-PID": "5055", "A-PID": "5155", "Uydu": "T4A"} ...

Comment: Key variable from list1,value variable from list2. List 1 is fix around 8 value, list2 is value of list1 and its over 500 row

Comment: Oh, i see what youre doing then.  Your code was not conveying what you are stating.  It looks like Mark Meyer may have an answer which suits you.  Give it a try let us know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert this to a list of dicts using a list comprehension and zipping the header with the row values. For example:

```
header = ["Company","MRP","Product","Selling_price"]
mainrow = [["TEST1","MRP1","Carrot","5"],
           ["TEST2","MRP2","Cheese","10"]
          ]

[dict(zip(header, r)) for r in mainrow]
```

Results in this list:

```
[{'Company': 'TEST1',
  'MRP': 'MRP1',
  'Product': 'Carrot',
  'Selling_price': '5'},
 {'Company': 'TEST2',
  'MRP': 'MRP2',
  'Product': 'Cheese',
  'Selling_price': '10'}]
```

Depending on how you are working with this data, a `namedtuple` might be a better choice than dictionaries.

```
from collections import namedtuple

header = ["Company","MRP","Product","Selling_price"]
mainrow = [["TEST1","MRP1","Carrot","5"],
           ["TEST2","MRP2","Cheese","10"]
          ]

row = namedtuple('Row', header)
data = [row(*r) for r in mainrow]
print(data[0].Product) #'Carrot'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would restructure your two lists into one big list of dictionaries, like so:

```py
import json

thing = [
    { "Company": TEST1",
      "MRP": "MRP",
      "Product": "Product",
      "Selling_price": "Selling_price"
    },
    { "Company": TEST2",
      "MRP": "MRP",
      "Product": "Product",
      "Selling_price": "Selling_price"
    }
]

with open('file.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(thing, f)
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

To restructure your lists, I would use something like this code:

```py
header = [
        "Company",
        "MRP",
        "Product",
        "Selling_price", #first list
    ]
mainrow = [[
        "TEST1",
        "MRP",
        "Carrot",
        "5", #second list first row
    ],
           [
        "TEST2",
        "MRP",
        "Cheese",
        "10", #second list second row
    ],
     ... #second list n row
]
thing = []
for row in mainrow:
    new_item = {}
    for i = 0; i < len(header); i++:
        new_item[header[i]] = row[i]
    thing.append(new_item)
```

Now just dump the newly created `thing` into JSON.

Comment: That is not possible first list has 8 variable(first list will be key of dict). Second list has 8 variable for all over 500 row (8 variable will be value of dict).